# Using FOREACH caluse in Memgrpah 2.1

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm running Memgrpah 2.1 (Platform docker image) and I can't get `FOREACH` caulse for me to work:

```
FOREACH ( a IN [1, 2, 3] | CREATE (n {age : a}))
MATCH (n) RETURN n.age
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FOREACH` clause was added in [Memgraph 2.3](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/changelog/#v230---apr-27-2022). You need to upgrade Memgraph version to be 2.3 or higher.